# Postgres check if column name is valid

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Oracle we have

```
select dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(TEST) from dual
```

what will be the equivalent in postgresql ? I can't seem to find anywhere the answer.

If column is wrong in Oracle we get:

```
 ORA-44003: invalid SQL name ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ASSERT", line 160
 44003. 0000 -  "invalid SQL name"
 *Document: Yes
 *Cause:    The input parameter string was not a valid simple SQL name.
 *Action:   Check with the DBMS_ASSERT spec to verify that the parameter
            string is a valid simple SQL name.
```

Comment: You can easily write such a function yourself using the specification from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_assert.htm#BABHIEBA).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly the same thing, but an "illegal" identifier has to be quoted in Postgres (and SQL). The function `format()` has a special place holder for identifiers and will return a quoted identifier if anything is non-standard:

So `select format('%I', 'foo')` returns `foo`.

But `select format('%I', 'foo bar')` returns `"foo bar"`

So if you check that the return value is quoted (starts with a `"`) then it's not a valid identifier.

This also checks for reserved keywords, so `select format('%I', 'order')` returns `"order"`